# Horizontal slider with blank space appearing on tablet and less width

Tags: html, css, web

I created PC friendly website, but i'm starting to make it responsive, but i got into a problem. For some reason at tablet and less width i'm getting white space which is comming from html according to inspector.

[image]

I tried to make body and height width to 100%, but it doesn't work. I honestly have no idea how to fix this.

```
My code in fiddle:
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taysim/msh53L0n/2/)

Comment: show your relevant code please

Comment: Edited my topic

Comment: You have to show us working code(I did the work and create fiddle):https://jsfiddle.net/x4mn68t1/

Comment: Ok, give me a second

Comment: your code too long so better to show in question the fiddle link(that I create for you)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/taysim/msh53L0n/

Comment: 1. You need change the size of headings on smaller screens. 2. Change the position and transform property of containers on smaller screens. That should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 issues that make space:

1. `<h2>Ką galiu <br/> garantuoti?</h2>` the font too big and make it out of container

   to solve it change to `font-size: 4em;`
2. your form position in side what make all page to be bigger
   to solve it

   `.centered {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 20%;}`

[**Here is working code**](https://jsfiddle.net/k6jtm7uq/)

Comment: Thanks. I understood everything what was messing with the screen width.

By the way, do you see any big issues that may lead to some problems in making website responsive? What should I think about, change. Not asking to rewrite the code for me. Just give me a heads up, what are my mistakes, etc.. If you have time for that of course :)